# Change screen when iOS app is brought to foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have an iOS app (written in Objective-C) which, when running in the background, will perform a background task to detect if you are moving greater than 5mph. If this has occurred (travelled > 5mph), a specific screen (screen123) is displayed when the app is brought to the foreground.

This currently works but when the app is brought to the foreground you briefly see the last screen that had been viewed from the previous use of the app (for about 1 second) before screen123 is displayed. Is there any way to have the app running in the background and when it is brought to the foreground to display screen123 immediately (without the previous screen displaying)?

The code that causes screen123 to be displayed is within `applicationWillEnterForeground` in AppDelegate.

Comment: Can you provide the code in `applicationWillEnterForeground` that you use to display screen123?

Comment: Have you tried just hiding your unwanted screen  in  applicationDidEnterBackground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS uses a snapshot of your last state, to hide the transition delay back to your app.  You are probably seeing this.

Read "Prepare to have your app’s picture taken" in ["Strategies for Handling App State Transitions"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW1) from Apple.

You are going to struggle to get rid of it entirely.  You should think about some way to smooth the transition.  Maybe you could have a screen that only contains the content that doesn't change, and then fade the "< 5mph" or "> 5mph" content onto the screen afterwards.